# Generate 'project.lock.json' as generated by Visual Studio using command line for Xamarin.iOS portable class library - Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, msbuild

Summary: Mac - OSX
Project: Portable library for Xamarin.iOS project

I have added newtonsoft.json package, so when I open project in visual studio it generates project.lock.json and the build works fine. But when I try to run from command line it is not working. 
Can you please suggest what command should I use to generate this file?

Answer (score 1):

The project.lock.json file is created during the NuGet package restore. This will be done automatically by Visual Studio.

From the command line you can generate the project.lock.json by one of the following:

- nuget restore /path/to/yoursolution.sln
- msbuild /t:restore /path/to/yoursolution.sln

Both of the above will recreate the project.lock.json file. Then you can build the solution.